# Windows command line compression/extraction tool?

Tags: command-line, compression, batch-file, unzip

I need to write a batch file to unzip files to their current folder from a given root folder.

```
Folder 0
    |----- Folder 1
    |          |----- File1.zip
    |          |----- File2.zip
    |          |----- File3.zip
    |
    |----- Folder 2
    |          |----- File4.zip
    |       
    |----- Folder 3
               |----- File5.zip
               |----- FileN.zip
```

So, I wish that my batch file is launched like so:

```
ocd.bat /d="Folder 0"
```

Then, make it iterate from within the batch file through all of the subfolders to unzip the files exactly where the .zip files are located.

So here's my question:

> **Does the Windows (from XP at least) have a command line for its embedded zip tool? Otherwise, shall I stick to another third-party util?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is not unzip tool shipped as part of Windows XP, but there is gnu [unzip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm) which will do the job nicely for you.

Comment: I've been told that there was this compression util embedded to Windows XP that is called `compress.exe`.

Comment: Compress doesn't know how to do anything with ZIP files, and is not available in all versions of XP.  If you need unzip functionality, you will need a 3rd party EXE.

Comment: I have finally decided to use `7za.exe` which is the command line version of 7-Zip.