# How to avoid the Windows (XP) Security Warning when launching a "DOS" command line within C#?

Tags: c#, command-line, .net-2.0, console, startprocessinfo

This question is related to [this initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967795/windows-command-line-compression-extraction-tool) asked a little while ago.

Now, that I have chosen the extracting tool, I'm iterating through a given in command line parameter directory and subdirectories to extract the compressed .zip files.

```
private static void ExtractAll(DirectoryInfo _workingFolder) {
    if(_workingFolder == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Répertoire inexistant.");
        return;
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in _workingFolder.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
        foreach(FileInfo zippedFile in subFolder.GetFiles("*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
            if(zippedFile.Exists) {
                ProcessStartInfo task = new ProcessStartInfo(@".\Tools\7za.exe", string.Format("x {0}", zippedFile.FullName));
                Process.Start(task);
            }
    }
}
```

But everytime I start a 7za process, the Windows Security Warning prompts. I would like to avoid such annoying behaviour, so here's my question:

**How to avoid the Windows (XP) Security Warning when launching a "DOS" command line within C#?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a guess at best(don't have the time to try), but maybe try using CreateNoWindow?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx

Here's the code after using the proposed solution:

```
private static void ExtractAll(DirectoryInfo _workingFolder) {
    if(_workingFolder == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Répertoire inexistant.");
        return;
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in _workingFolder.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
        foreach(FileInfo zippedFile in subFolder.GetFiles("*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
            if(zippedFile.Exists) {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Extraction du fichier : {0}", zippedFile.FullName));
                Process task = new Process();
                task.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                task.StartInfo.FileName = @".\Tools\7za.exe";
                task.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("x {0}", zippedFile.FullName);
                task.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                task.Start();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Extraction de {0} terminée", zippedFile.FullName));
                //ProcessStartInfo task = new ProcessStartInfo(@".\Tools\7za.exe", string.Format("x {0}", zippedFile.FullName));
                //Process.Start(task);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another way around this is by signing your exe if you can figure out how to do that

link - http://www.csharp411.com/net-assembly-faq-part-3-strong-names-and-signing/